# Generated listview contains only last variable in Intent putExtra

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I want to add to putExtra some unique variables for each generated element in ListView. It generating a list of tv shows and i want to putExtra id for each serie, onClick it makes intent which opens activity with info about serie. But it putExtra the variables of the last searched element. (The names on element are correct, but only in putExtra are variables of the last position) This is my code:

```
class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<MovieModel> movieModelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    LinearLayout linear;
    FrameLayout framel;
    Button btn1;
    TextView txv;
    Intent intent;

    private String ide;
    private String name;
    private String overview;
    private String poster_path;
    int pos;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MovieModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        movieModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }
        name = movieModelList.get(position).getName();
        overview = movieModelList.get(position).getOverview();
        ide = movieModelList.get(position).getId() + "";
        poster_path = movieModelList.get(position).getPoster_path();

        pos = position;

        txv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        btn1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        linear = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linear);


        txv.setText(name);
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SerieActivity.class);
    linear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent intent;
            intent.putExtra("id", ide);
            intent.putExtra("name", name);
            intent.putExtra("overview", overview);
            intent.putExtra("poster_path", poster_path);
            startActivity(intent);
            movieModelList.clear();

        }
    });
        // btn1.setText((id));


        return convertView;
    }

    public void click(String id) {
        btn1.setText(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: You variables that have scope of the whole class, you want them just in the method. move `ide name overview poster_path` into the `getView` method and it should be fine

Comment: But then i cant use them in onclick because "this variables are in other class" or something like that

Comment: Still the same problem, even when i made putExtra("id",movieModelList.get(position).getName()) ;